# What is core_file_storage table in Magento?

Tags: database

I have `core_file_storage` table in Magento with very huge size. What is it's functionality? Can I remove and replace functionality? Is it affects to the speed of my database? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento can store media files in database.

Check `Configuration \ Advanced \ System \ Storage Configuration for Media`.

The main reason for storing media in database is the case when you use balancing servers and don't want to bother with shared directories. All the rest is performance degradation.

I suggest switching to filesystem storage. Files will be synchronised automatically by Magento with click on "Sync" button at the admin screen posted above.

Comment: Nice bit about the 'sync' feature.

Comment: One of the projects I was working on was hacked via this module, took a while to discover that shell was stored there.

Answer (score 3):

It's for storing media files in the database. Files are retrieved from the database with the file `get.php` in the Magento Root.

To disable this feature navigate in the system admin to:

```
Configuration > Advanced > System > Storage Configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

This table is backed by: Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage

It stores media files, as BLOBs in the DB, and can lead to issues with performance.

The intent behind this is for distributing the Media files across a larger installation, or even being able to extrapolate the storage system into something besides mysql or files.

The settings for this are in the admin: Configuration->Advanced->System->Storage Configuration for Media. Switching that setting to files, should remove the files from that table, thus shrinking it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch back to file system. 
Check:

> Configuration \ Advanced \ System \ Storage Configuration for
>   Media.

Select File System for Media Storage

Then hit Synchronize

It will take several hours to finish the synchronization

**Don't hit save** after the synchronization done.