# truncate core_file_storage

Tags: database

The Magento server I am working on was set up by another person to use database storage.

Without knowing this, I have been running an image import script which has failed now with the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'core_file_storage' is
>   full'

What are my options if I cannot synchronize to file system storage?

Is it safe to truncate `core_file_storage`? Does it contain anything other than images/media?

Comment: no,it core_file_storage  save all the magento images.

Comment: @AmitBera so it is safe to truncate it?

Comment: Truncating it will lead to issues as all the images stored will disappear. Is it giving the error when you try to import or is the site down hard with the error? Changing media storage to file is supposed to extract the images out to file storage => http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16601/what-is-core-file-storage-table-in-magento

Comment: @FiascoLabs I am currently in the process of changing media storage to file. It has now been synchronizing for over 15 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Synchronization process 'finished' after ~60hrs with a major error of `An error has occured while syncronizing media storages.`

I have purchased an increase in disk space from my hosting provider and reattempted synchronization. I can see by watching the media/catalog folder increase in size that everything is working correctly.

I would have preferred Magento to give an error that it cannot write to disk rather than spend over two days creating thousands of empty image files but lesson learned I guess.