# how store media in database?

Tags: magento-2.1

When I try to save the media from the admin panel in store-> configuration-> advanced-> system-> Storage Configuration for Media
I set Media Storage: Database and select a db and sync but this does not work, when I see the image url of a product it shows something like:
"Http: //m2.local/get.php/tmp/catalog/product/t/e/test_5.jpg" I do not know what that "get.php" means if I set back the media file to the local file system the images work fine .

I'm skipping a step? I do not see any new tables in the database. and not erros in exception log.

Comment: The get.php file handles all requests of media if you use the database location. If it has write access to Magento's file system, it searches for existing files, create them, if false and deliver them to the user.
If it has no write access, the scripts delivers them always directly.

Comment: Just a bling guess: Maybe you cancelled the sync accidentally. According to [another answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/68720/47310), try avoiding to save after sync.